# probability of ${Unif(0,1)^2}$

Tags: probability, distribution-theory, uniform-distribution

I am new to probability theory. In computer programming, I often use the uniform random number in $(0,1)$
     $$
U= Unif(0,1)
$$
what is the probability density of $U^2$?

In general, how to find the probability of  $\sqrt{U}, \ln{U}, \frac{1}{U}$, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I will illustrate how to deal with $U^2$ and leave the rest as an exercise.

First think of what are the possible range of values that $U^2$ can take.

Suppose $t \in (0,1)$,

\begin{align}
Pr(U^2 \le t) &= Pr (U \le \sqrt{t}), \\
&= \sqrt{t}
\end{align}

Now, you just have to diffferentiate it to recover the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The law of the unconscious statistician (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) may be what you're looking for. It says that
$$ \mathbb{E}(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f(x) \ dx $$
Or for discrete random variables
$$ \mathbb{E}(g(X)) = \sum_{i\in S} g(i) \mathbb{P}(X=i)\ dx $$
This allows you to compute the expectation and variance of various transforms of a given random variable $X$.

Comment: could you please just show how to apply this law to the case of $x^2$

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f(x) \ dx$ where $f$ is the pdf of $X$.